# MATLAB/Python array difference?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix

I got the following:

- redIdx: a 2x1 matrix with values (289485, 289486).
- image: 366x791x3 uint8 matrix (an image).
- image2: zeros matrix with the same sape as image.

In MATLAB, if I do image2(redIdx) it returns a 2x1 matrix with values (0,0) and if I do image(redIdx) it returns a 2x1 matrix with values (94, 83).

But in Python, if I do image2[redIdx] or image[redIdx], it returns the next error: index 2879485 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 366.

How can I get the same result as MATLAB?

Comment: It seems like you want _linear indexing_ in Python. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41914872/2586922) helps

Comment: I'm trying but don't know yet how to do it

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB, when indexing an array with a single index (as opposed to multiple ones) uses [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2). Python, in the same situation, uses the index to index into the first dimension, returning a slice. The fact that `redIdx` contains multiple values is irrelevant, it's a 1D indexing operation.

To replicate linear indexing in Python, you can [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the array, then index:

```py
image.flatten('K')[redIdx]
```

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914872/how-to-use-a-linear-index-to-access-a-2d-array-in-python) shows how to compute indices from the single linear index, which would be a more complex alternative to the above.